# How to get the SMS sender address in Android

Tags: android, parsing, sms

I'm new to Android. I'm developing an application and I need to fetch the sender while parsing the message. We will be receiving biz messages like IM-ICICI, fb-623525 etc. I want to know how can I get the SMS address of such alphanumeric character senders.